# Meaning of ddl -p9 apppackagename.zip *unzip=apppackagename.zip command

Tags: command, verifone

I am using verifone device. So to install that application some step are provided. So there is many command they give to install application.

i want to know when we use below command ?

" ddl -p9 apppackagename.zip *unzip=apppackagename.zip "

i want to explore this command. So from where i can explore it ?

Answer (score 1):

Download:

- -p9 --> using port 9 (-p specifies the port)
- apppackagename.zip --> push this file
- *unzip=apppackagename.zip --> set "*unzip" in the config.sys to the value "apppackagename.zip".  The effect of having "*unzip=`string`"
  is that on boot-up the terminal will look for the file "`string`" and if it finds it, it will try to unzip it.  After unzipping, it will
  set "*unzip" to 1, as I recall. This will leave a record that you had a *unzip, but won't try to unzip it again next time it boots. (the format `string1`=`string2` sets something in the config)

Note that this does not specify the group, so it will just use the group you specified when you initiate the download (you can't set an arbitrary group unless you start in 1)

Answer (score 0):

This commands loads file `apppackagename.zip` into respective group and tells OS to unzip this archive file after next restart.

Terminal must be in the "ready for download" mode.

See the respective Operating System Manual for more details (section "Environment Variables Application Information").